# Calling the cloudbees sdk from jenkins @ cloudbees

Tags: sdk, jenkins, java-7, cloudbees

I have an instance of Jenkins running at Build@Cloud that build a WAR running JDK7. From my computer, I call the Cloudbees SDK bees:app deploy command with the -Rjava_version=1.7 in order to specify the JDK to use at runtime.

However, using the Cloudbees Deploy plugin in Jenkins, I cannot specify such a runtime parameter. And on the other hand, I cannot call the SDK commands directly.

Is there a documented way to specify the -Rjava_version=1.7 option from the Jenkins instance?

Thanks for any help,
Damien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this parameter once using the SDK, all subsequent deployments for the same application ID will reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

If, for other reasons, you still want to use the CloudBees SDK there is a solution:
 http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Scripting+Bees+SDK+in+Jenkins

For example I wanted to deploy a simple java application (not a WebApp). So had to do this:

```
bees app:deploy -a brnvrn/gdataaccess -t java -R class=com.brnvrn.test.Main -R classpath=gdataaccess.jar target\gdataaccess.zip waitForApplicationStart=false
```